# CSS event on one element, changing an other

Tags: css, hover, element

How can i change an element with CSS with an event on another element?

```
E.g. <div id="one"> ....., <div id="two">....

<style>
#one:hover
{
changing the visibility of #two...
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

In your case, with the element you wish to change being *after* the element you hover, meaning that you have a structure like:

```
<div id="one"></div>
<!--you could have some elements between them-->
<div id="two"></div>
```

or like:

```
<div id="one">
    <!--maybe some elements-->
        <div id="two"></div>
    <!---->
</div>
```

In the first case (`#one` and `#two` are *siblings*, that is they are on the same level = have the same parent), you use [**the general sibling combinator**](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) (`~`), like this:

```
#one:hover ~ #two { /* style changes */ }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/UpXfS/1/) for the case when `#one` and `#two` are siblings and `#one` is before `#two` in the HTML.

In the second case (`#two` is a *descendant* of `#one`), you use:

```
#one:hover #two { /* style changes */ }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/UpXfS/3/) for the case when `#two` is a descendant of `#one`.

However, if you wish to change an element that is *before* `#one` in the HTML, then that is currently ([meaning that this could change in the future](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/)) impossible with CSS alone (if you would like to know why, then [this article](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors) offers an explanation).

---

But in this case, when `#two` is before `#one` in the HTML, you can do it with JavaScript. For instance, if the opacity of `#two` is initially `0`, then you could change it to `1` when hovering `#one` using:

```
var one = document.getElementById('one'),
    two = document.getElementById('two');
one.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    two.style.opacity = 1;
}, true);
one.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    two.style.opacity = 0;
}, true);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/UpXfS/4/)

And if you're using a library like jQuery, then it gets even easier:

```
$('#one').hover(function(){
    $('#two').css({'opacity': 1})},
function(){
    $('#two').css({'opacity': 0})
});​​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/UpXfS/5/)

Answer (score 3):

Use a combination of the `:hover` selector and the `~` General Sibling selector:

```
div.margin:hover ~.margin2
{
    background: #00f;
}
```

Hover over div 2 and you'll see the other div change.

For this to work, the divs must be siblings (have the same parent element).

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/mmcRp/