# One object changes another objects background image...?

Tags: css, html, button

I am making a quiz project, like a TV game show, and when a player hovers or selects their quiz response, a light on the side of the game board lights up.

Basically, I'd like a hover and a click to change the background image of a separate object. 
Please help me to do this.

I am using CSS and HTML5

Thank you.

Comment: With CSS only I think this can only be done if you have the “separate object” as a sibling of the button elements, so that you can use the _general sibling combinator_ in a selector like `.button:hover ~ #separateElement` to target the latter. So if you can arrange that DOM structure and can position your separate element absolutely or fixed to get it to the desired position, that could work. Otherwise, you might need to use JavaScript as well.

Comment: Everything I've tried has been rather naive. Such as putting both elements into the same <a> element, or stuff like that. I couldn't find any help that fit my needs exctly, and my skill is still rather low.

Answer (score 0):

Oh. The joy.

Mooseman's suggestion about sibling combinators helped me find this post:
[CSS event on one element, changing an other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459301/css-event-on-one-element-changing-an-other)

Sorry that my post is redundant. 
But I'm just glad I got it working.

Thank you.